# Refencing in MongoDB schema

Tags: mongodb

I'm very new to mongoDB and im learning about schema's. Now ive watched some tutorials on referencing, embedding etc. so now im trying to come up with a simple schema for a text game that users can sign up to a game and create a player in the game. I came up with a simple schema:

**Game collection:**

```
Game 1 - '{ 
“_id” = ObjectId (“1”),
“Name” = “Game 1”
“Start date” = “01-05-2022 02.00”
“End date” = “01-05-2022 02.00”
“Game status” = “Active”
“Players” = [ 
ObjectId (“11”), 
ObjectId (“22”)
      ]
 }
```

Players could potentially be alot, so im not embedding but referencing to the object ids of the players and store player information for that game in another collection.

**Player collection**

```
Player 1 - '{ 
“_id” = ObjectId (“11”),
“User” = ObjectId (“AAA”)
“Name” = “Player 1”
“Game entry” = “01-05-2022 02.00”
“Rank” =  “20”
“Assets” = [ 
“Hoes” = 2
“Thugs” = 3
“
 }
```

Now my question is what do i store in the user collection. I want to display a game history on a user page. Do i reference player Id's and trough that look up the games. Or reference the game and display the player name connected to that. Or both? What would be best practise to do? Storing both seems weird to me since there is no connection between them. I can't find a good similar example to be able to learn from it.

**User collection**

```
User 1 - { 
“_id” = ObjectId (“AAA”),
“Username” = “xxx” 
“E-mail” = “x@x.com”
“Password = “dfkjhgkfh”
“Games” = [
ObjectId (“1”)
ObjectId (“3”)
ObjectId (“5”)
[
}
```

Thanks!

As i said I have been watching MongoDB tutorials to get a grasp of the basic concept. I think im clear on what one-one on-many and many to many etc. means but still i'm doubting what the best approach is.